# Fetching entities in OneToOne Mapping returns wrong results

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this entities

ResourceForSearch.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RESOURCES")
public class ResourceForSearch {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "IDRESOURCE")
    private long id;

    private String defaultText;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "IDRESOURCE", referencedColumnName = "IDRESOURCE")
    private TranslationForSearch translation;

    // getters and setters

}
```

TranslationForSearch.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSLATIONS")
public class TranslationForSearch {

    @Column(name = "IDTRANSLATION")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "IDLANGUAGE")
    private long languageId;

    private String translation;

    @Id
    private long idResource;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Normally a `RESOURCE` is in relation with N `TRANSLATION`(s) and a `TRANSLATION` is identified by `IDTRANSLATION`, but given a value for `TRANSLATIONS.IDLANGUAGE`, this relation becomes `OneToOne` because in a certain language (identified by `IDLANGUAGE`) the translation is only one for each resource (a resource is a label I want to translate in different languages).

So only for search purposes I can put the `@Id` annotation on the `TranslationForSearch.idResource` field, not on the `TranslationForSearch.id` field.

Here is the Criteria query I wrote:

```
CriteriaQuery<ResourceForSearch> searchQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(ResourceForSearch.class);
Root<ResourceForSearch> searchRoot = searchQuery.from(ResourceForSearch.class);
searchQuery.select(searchRoot);
Join<ResourceForSearch, TranslationForSearch> translationJoin = resourceRoot.join("translation", JoinType.LEFT);
// Here I filter the JOIN clause by language id, having the OneToOne relationship 
translationJoin.on(criteriaBuilder.equal(translationJoin.get("languageId"), 22)); 
// Here I want to fetch the TRANSLATIONS included in the join
resourceRoot.fetch("translation");
List<ResourceForSearch> resultList = em.createQuery(searchQuery).getResultList();
```

The problem here is that the statement

```
for (ResourceForSearch resourceForSearch : resultList) {
    if (resourceForSearch.getTranslation() != null)
        System.out.println("Resource id: " + resourceForSearch.getId() + " Language id: " + resourceForSearch.getTranslation().getLanguageId());
}
```

Prints

```
Resource id: 81 Language id 22
Resource id: 85 Language id 30
Resource id: 86 Language id 30
Resource id: 87 Language id 30
Resource id: 88 Language id 30
```

It seems that the fetch in the query doesn't work because the query is returning  entities which doesn't respect the join clause.

EDIT 1:
This is the SQL query generated by Hibernate

```
SELECT resourcefo0_.IDRESOURCE AS IDRESOURCE1_2_,
  resourcefo0_.defaultText     AS defaultText6_2_
FROM WIN_RESOURCES resourcefo0_
LEFT OUTER JOIN WIN_TRANSLATIONS translatio1_
ON resourcefo0_.IDRESOURCE  =translatio1_.idResource
AND (translatio1_.IDLANGUAGE =22)
```

Which returns a number of rows equal to the numbero of rows of WIN_RESOURCES. Moreover if I edit the query adding the select field translatio1_.IDLANGUAGE, it returns me a value of 22 of null (not 30).

```
SELECT resourcefo0_.IDRESOURCE AS IDRESOURCE1_2_,
  resourcefo0_.defaultText     AS defaultText6_2_,
  translatio1_.IDLANGUAGE
FROM WIN_RESOURCES resourcefo0_
LEFT OUTER JOIN WIN_TRANSLATIONS translatio1_
ON resourcefo0_.IDRESOURCE  =translatio1_.idResource
AND (translatio1_.IDLANGUAGE =22)
```

Where can be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: if this is one to one relationship, then how come multiple resources are tagged to single language?

Comment: saying something doesn't respect a join clause would imply that you have actually looked at the SQL generated. You have, haven't you?

Comment: @PrasadKharkar: because for a single resource and a single language Id you have a single tuple in the TRANSLATION table.